# Coefficients of polynomials maxima

Tags: maxima, polynomials, degrees, coefficients

Is there a built-in function in maxima to get from a polynomial function a list with its coefficients? And to get the degree of the polynomial?

The most similar function I found is `args`, but it also returns the variable together with the coefficient. I could have accepted this, still more when using `length` together with `args` would return the degree. The problem is that `args` doesn't work with zero-degree polynomials.

Is there another function that adjusts better to these purposes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To compute the degree of a polynomial in one variable, you can use the `hipow` function.

```
(%i) p1 : 3*x^5 + x^2 + 1$
(%i) hipow(p1,x);
(%o)                                5
```

For a polynomial with more than one variable, you can map `hipow` over the variables returned by the `listofvars` function, and then take the maximum of the resulting list.

```
(%i) p2 : 4*y^8 - 3*x^5 + x^2 + 1$
(%i) degree(p) := if integerp(p) then 0 else 
            lmax(map (lambda([u], hipow(p,u)),listofvars(p)))$
(%i) degree(p1);
(%o)                                5
(%i) degree(p2);
(%o)                                8
(%i) degree(1);
(%o)                                0
```

The `coeff` function returns the coefficient of `x^n`, given `coeff(p,x,n)`, so to generate a list of the coefficients of a polynomial in one variable, we can iterate through the powers of x, saving the coefficients to a list.

```
(%i) coeffs1(p,x) := block([l], l : [], 
                         for i from 0 thru hipow(p,x)     
                             do (l : cons(coeff(p,x,i),l)), l)$
(%i) coeffs1(p1,x);
(%o)                       [3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

And to generate a list of the coefficients of a polynomial in more than one variable, map `coeffs1` over the `listofvars`.

```
(%i) coeffs(p) := map(lambda([u], coeffs1(p, u)), listofvars(p))$
(%i) coeffs(p2);
(%o) [[- 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4 y^8  + 1], 
         [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, - 3 x^5  + x^2  + 1]]
```

Comment: your degree is only max-hipow, but not max-monomial degree. The later could for example give degree(x^2*y-x) = 3.

Comment: Definitely no built-in command to get the whole list of coefficients? Must program?